# how do i use a temporary date table combine with three other Tables to extract all customer info using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i want to Write a query using the temporary date table to show rows for every customer for every month since the month they first purchased from us. The table should detail the customer ID, customer name, month,  Date of first Purchase, Units Purchased that month, Value Purchased that month, Cumulative Units Purchased, Cumulative Value Purchased and the Days since last purchase and the last day of the month.

i've tried this code

```
select c.Id AS CustomerId
,c.FirstName+' '+c.LastName as CustomerName
,DATENAME(MM,d.OrderDate) AS  MonthofFirstPurchase
--,sum(d.TotalAmount) AS CummulativeValue
,d.OrderDate AS DateOfFirstPurchase
,Datediff(dd,o.OrderDate,getdate()) as DateSinceLastPurchase 
from[dbo].[Customer]c inner join [dbo].[Order] b on b.CustomerId = c.Id
join (select max(Id) as OrderId, min(Id) as minOrder,[CustomerId] from [dbo].[Order] group by [CustomerId])conn on c.Id = conn.[CustomerId]
join [dbo].[Order]o on o.[Id] = conn.OrderId
join [dbo].[Order]d on d.[Id] = conn.minOrder
--join [dbo].[OrderItem]b on  = conn.OrderId
```

but i keep getting errors i am a beginner at this

Comment: Unless you share the error message we are left guessing.

Comment: I would urge you to use some spacing in your queries. Cramming everything together with no spaces is fine for the compiler but is horrible for humans. Also, you should avoid reserved words like Order for object names. And last but not least using the names of dateparts is a lot easier to remember. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations (see the section on dateparts). :) As posted, your query will parse so syntactically it appears to be ok.

Comment: I was expecting to get a single result that shows the all the order details for the first date of purchase for a customer, but the result ends up showing customer order details for multiple date due the fact that i need to group also by order date

Comment: the error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'dbo.Customer.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please format properly.  People will not read that query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please note that I did not execute the query.**

If you do not want that column please try the below query. I did not execute the query though

```
;WITH CTE_Temp
AS
(
SELECT max(Id) AS OrderId
        , min(Id) AS minOrder
        , [CustomerId]
    FROM [dbo].[Order]
    GROUP BY [CustomerId]
)
SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId
    , c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS CustomerName
    , DATENAME(MM, d.OrderDate) AS MonthofFirstPurchase
    --,sum(d.TotalAmount) AS CummulativeValue
    , d.OrderDate AS DateOfFirstPurchase
    , Datediff(dd, o.OrderDate, getdate()) AS DateSinceLastPurchase
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] b ON b.CustomerId = c.Id
INNER JOIN CTE_Temp conn ON c.Id = conn.[CustomerId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] o ON o.[Id] = conn.OrderId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] d ON d.[Id] = conn.minOrder
```

If you need the `sum(d.TotalAmount) AS CummulativeValue`. Just try the query

```
;WITH CTE_Temp
AS
(
SELECT max(Id) AS OrderId
        , min(Id) AS minOrder
        , [CustomerId]
    FROM [dbo].[Order]
    GROUP BY [CustomerId]
),
CTE_TEMP1
AS
(
SELECT CTE_Temp.[CustomerId], sum(d.TotalAmount) TotalAmount AS CummulativeValue
FROM [dbo].[Order] d INNER JOIN CTE_Temp ON d.[Id] = CTE_Temp.minOrder  
GROUP BY CTE_TEMP.[CustomerId]
)
SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId
    , c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS CustomerName
    , DATENAME(MM, d.OrderDate) AS MonthofFirstPurchase
    ,CTE_TEMP1.TotalAmount AS CummulativeValue
    , d.OrderDate AS DateOfFirstPurchase
    , Datediff(dd, o.OrderDate, getdate()) AS DateSinceLastPurchase
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] b ON b.CustomerId = c.Id
INNER JOIN CTE_Temp conn ON c.Id = conn.[CustomerId]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] o ON o.[Id] = conn.OrderId
INNER JOIN CTE_TEMP1 d ON d.CustomerId = c.id
```

Comment: Thank you Gopakumar your answer was of great help

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the anser provided by Gopakumar and i came to the solution of the problem. The code below works perfectly well for its purpose

```
;WITH CTE_Temp
AS
(
SELECT max(Id) AS MaxOrder
        , min(Id) AS MinOrder
        , [CustomerId]
    FROM [dbo].[Order]
    GROUP BY [CustomerId]
),

CTE_TEMP1 AS(SELECT CTE_TEMP.CustomerId,sum([UnitQuantity]) AS UnitsPurchasedForMonth,sum(TotalAmount) AS ValueForMonth 
from [dbo].[OrderItem]p left outer join [dbo].[Order] e on p.Id = e.Id 
INNER JOIN CTE_Temp ON e.[Id] = CTE_Temp.minOrder GROUP BY CTE_TEMP.CustomerId),

CTE_TEMP2 AS(SELECT e.CustomerId,sum([UnitQuantity]) AS CummulativeUnitsPurchased,sum(TotalAmount) AS CummulativeValue 
from [dbo].[OrderItem]p inner join [dbo].[Order] e on p.Id = e.Id group by e.CustomerId)





SELECT c.Id AS CustomerId
    , c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS CustomerName
    , DATENAME(MM, o.OrderDate) AS MonthofFirstPurchase
      , o.OrderDate AS DateOfFirstPurchase
    ,d.ValueForMonth AS ValuePurchasedForMonth 
    ,d.UnitsPurchasedForMonth
    ,e.CummulativeUnitsPurchased
    ,e.CummulativeValue
    , Datediff(dd, a.OrderDate, getdate()) AS DateSinceLastPurchase
    ,EOMONTH(o.OrderDate) AS LastDayOfMonth
FROM [dbo].[Customer] c
INNER JOIN CTE_Temp conn ON c.Id = conn.CustomerId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] o ON o.[Id] = conn.MinOrder
INNER JOIN CTE_TEMP1 d ON d.CustomerId = c.id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order] a on a.Id = conn.MaxOrder 
inner join CTE_TEMP2 e on c.Id = e.CustomerId
```

you can edit as you like to get your results